# Question regarding match filter implementation in receiver

Tags: digital-communications

For example, if you have a QAM 16, which mean there are 16 symbols.  Each symbol will have different level of the QAM constellation.  Each symbol will have a corresponding match filter.  At the receiver, there is a bank of match filter to match with each received symbol.
The receiver will use threshold to detect which has the highest threshold of that matched filter array.  My question is, let's say you have two symbols: one with high level and one with lower level.  Is it guaranteed that only the symbol that got "matched" will have the highest threshold level after the matched filter output?
I mean, can the high level symbol have a higher output after the matched filter even if it is not matched vs. a lower level symbol that is matched?

Comment: "each symbol will have a corresponding matched filter": no. That's not what a matched filter is. Revisit the definition of "matched filter".

Comment: Reading your question literally, the answer to your question is Yes, the matched filter for the symbol that got "matched" will have the largest (positive) output, but as Marcus Muller (sort of) points out, we don't have $M$ matched filters for the $M$ signals in $M$-QAM, just as we don't have two separate matched filters for the two signals in antipodal BPSK. We have one matched filter and we threshold at $0$ for antipodal BPSK, and we have two matched filters (in the I and Q branches respectively) and we threshold at $0$ and $\pm 2A$ for signal levels $-3A,-A,+A,+3A$ in each branch.